# Getting token values from for loop in Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm new to Windows batch scripting.
Trying to get values out of text file, Ignore.txt file and store them as local variables.

**Command File:**

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%i in (Ignore.txt) do (
    echo. %%i
    echo. %%j
    echo. %%k

  set value1=%%i
  set value2=%%j
  set value3=%%k
)

Echo. Value1: !value1!
Echo. Value2: !value2!
Echo. Value3: !value3!

Endlocal
```

**Ignore.txt:**

```
*.svc
*.jpg
*.png
```

But the result is only printing one variable that too wrong:

**Output:**

```
 *.svc
 *.jpg
 *.png

 Value1: *.png
 Value2:
 Value3:
```

Please help me if I'm doing anything wrong here. Also any suggestions on other better ways of retrieving this information.

Comment: The `for` loop processes one line at a time, and the lines in your file only have one token (which will be consumed by `%%i`), so `%%j` and `%%k` are NULL.

Comment: @CristiFati, If that's the case, how come echo is printing values properly?

Comment: _Ignore.txt_ has 3 lines: the `for` loop executes 3 times and each time only `echo. %%i` generates output on screen, the other 2 (since the variables are NULL/empty) are suppressed by `@Echo off`.

Comment: @CristiFati, Thank you. That helped me understand how it worked.

Comment: The main difficulty in your case is that the FOR loop does not know how to set newline characters as a delimiter. There is example when FOR loop get several variables from text using space delimiter by default `FOR /F "tokens=1-5" %%A IN ("This is a short sentence") DO (echo %%A %%D %%E)` will return "This short sentence"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help for `for`'s `token` option contains this bit:

```
tokens=x,y,m-n  - specifies which tokens from each line are to
                 be passed to the for body for each iteration.
```

In other words, it will only split a single line into multiple variables.  This is evidenced by the run of your script:  It outputs each line, but it's outputting empty lines between each one where the empty %%j and %%k are.

If you want to parse this file into separate variables, you'll need to track which line you're on manually, with something like this:

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _digit=1
for /F %%i in (Ignore.txt) do (
    echo. %%i

    set value!_digit!=%%i
    set /a _digit=!_digit!+1
)

Echo. Value1: !value1!
Echo. Value2: !value2!
Echo. Value3: !value3!

Endlocal
```

Comment: for WIndows 10 `FOR /F "tokens=1-5" %%A IN ("This is a short sentence") DO (echo %%A %%D %%E)` will return "This short sentence"

Answer (score 0):

The main difficulty in your case is that the FOR loop does not know how to set newline characters as a delimiter. So first you need to discard the newline character, such as collecting all the lines of a file into a text variable with a specific delimiter. After which it becomes possible to obtain the values of several variables.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Catenate all file lines in the same variable separated by %del%
SET "text="
SET "del=~"
FOR /F %%a IN (Ignore.txt) DO (SET "text=!text!%del%%%a")
ECHO %text%

:: obtain the values of several variables.
FOR /F "delims=%del% tokens=1-6" %%i IN ("%text%") DO (
  echo. %%i
  echo. %%j
  echo. %%k

  set value1=%%i
  set value2=%%j
  set value3=%%k
)
Echo. Value1: !value1!
Echo. Value2: !value2!
Echo. Value3: !value3!
```

**Output**

```
 *.svc
 *.jpg
 *.png
 Value1: *.svc
 Value2: *.jpg
 Value3: *.png
```